# Update ListView from user input after setContentView call

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, android-listview

I want to show an empty list view, which is then populated by user input. I have the UI flow working, and I populate a list of my custom objects after the user enters some information via a view which is invoked through setContentView (i.e. no a new Activity).

I take the input and add it to a list, which I want to be summarised on the ListView. However, whenever I add to the list and/or the ArrayAdapter and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() it does not do what I want. The ListView is still empty. Argh! It's driving me insane!

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle blah) {
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.results_list);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.mnu_add:
        final Activity act = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.record_details);// the sub-view that takes the user input
        // the button on the form to 'add' details:-
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.recored_details_add_btn))
        .setOnClickListener(
            new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    // get input from widgets 
                    list.add(someObject);
                    ((ArrayAdapter<Object>) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);

                }
            }
        );
        ((ArrayAdapter<Object>) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Please, save me from my misery and inform me of my stupidty?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // get input from widgets 
    list.add(someObject);
    ((ArrayAdapter<Object>) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    setContentView(R.layout.list_view);
```

Is it possible that this `setContentView` in the `onClick` handler is creating a new instance of the list view widget (with no adapter) or reinitializing the list view (clearing the adapter)?

Try putting something in the list initially in `onCreate` and then see if it disappears when you hit the button.

I haven't seen any code (although I'm a relative newbie) that switches views within the activity's lifetime to bring up essentially bring up different pages - most use a separate activity.

*Edit:*

OP asks:

> Thanks...So how can I get what I want? The list I'm backing the adapter with is static; should I just use activities instead and rely on onCreate loading from the static field?

Some options:

1. Use separate activities
2. Re-associate the adapter (call `setAdapter` again) - probably a bad idea
3. Declare both layouts in the same file. You'll hide one and unhide the other to switch between views rather can calling `setContentView`. This is similar to how ListView layout works (one for when the list is empty and one for when it is not).  I think I've seen an example of this somewhere on the net, but I don't have a reference right now.

Comment: I added an instance of the same custom class in onCreate which is visible on first view (well, the result of toString is visible), but disappears when I click the add button on the sub-view!

Comment: @atc - I think that confirms the theory.  You're creating/reinitializing the list view when you call `setContentView()`. Regardless of which, the adapter is no longer associated.  There could be other side-effects to calling `setContentView` multiple times.

Comment: Thanks...So how can I get what I want? The list I'm backing the adapter with is static; should I just use activities instead and rely on onCreate loading from the static field?

Comment: I've amended the above code using startActivity instead and this works fine because of the field's static nature. Doesn't feel right!

Answer (score 1):

You could relaunch the same activity by using `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag while creating the intent and override the `onNewIntent()` method.

Inside the `onNewIntent()` you create the adapter with updated data and call `setAdapter`.

I think this will give you the intended behaviour.